# Spark sql about rddToDataFrameHolder

Tags: apache-spark

I've coded a jar to run on the Spark,my project's include jars is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGIc8.png)

and my spark on hadoop is spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7
When I run my jar [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8XYg.png)
is the version conflicts?
follow is my code

```
case class VehicleInfo(vin: String, vehicle_license: String, sales_id: String)
```

object ChangeStatus {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

```
//txt path in hdfs
val path = args(0)

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("change_status")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext.implicits._

val input = sc.textFile(path)
  .map(line => line.split("\\|"))
  .map(line => VehicleInfo(line(0), line(1), line(2)))
  .toDF()

input.registerTempTable("vehicle_info")

val result_df = sqlContext.sql("select * from vehicle_info limit 10")

result_df.show()
```

}
}

what is the problem about my code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you are running against Spark 2.0.2, but compiling against Spark 1.5.1. Usually Spark is pretty good about compatibility - even at a binary level. However this crosses major versions and is bound to have breaking changes. So, I'd say to just compile against 2.0.2